# NSAttributedString from HTML with cyrillic support

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, cyrillic

I am using this code to get NSAttributedString from someHtmlString and put this into UITextView

```
    let data = Data(someHtmlString.utf8)
    if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data,
           options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
           documentAttributes: nil) {
       myTextView.attributedText = attributedString
    }
```

I got problems with cyrillic letters, while server's response encoding is UTF-8, if I don't put

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

at the beginning of someHtmlString, I can't show it correctly.

Comment: You did not provide a concrete example, but I am fairly sure that the problem is the missing encoding attribute. Otherwise let me know and I’ll reopen the question.

Comment: I opened question with your answer that you are pointing to. It is not compiling.